# Error using hyperref with memoir

Tags: hyperref, memoir

Starting with an update in October 2020 hyperref stopped working when using the memoir class. Is this a known issue?
MWE is attached:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
This is not working!
\end{document}
```

Comment: memoir has already been updated to avoid the error. It should reach you soon.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response!

Comment: Add `\renewcommand\AtEndPackage[2]{\def\temp{\AddToHook{package/after/#1}{#2}}\temp}` before loading hyperref, that should work until the update is there.

Comment: Note that this fix only works because `hyperref` auto loads `memhfixc.sty` where `memoirs` adjustments for `hyperrerf` lives. Uses of `\AtEndPackage` inside `memoir` it self cannot be fixed like that (I just learned the hard way).

Comment: @daleif you mean you can't define AtEndPackage in memoir to have that definition (in new formats) so always require doubled `#` as before ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle no, you cannot use the fix Ulrike gave for `\AtEndPackage` for executions of `\AtEndPackage` already executed by a non-updated `memoir`, for example for `caption`

Comment: @daleif ah Ok yes I see what you mean now, thanks.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but the correct use of `\RemoveFromHook` can

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Should we close the question as "solved in comments"?